# How to plot graph for coverage area

Tags: matlab

I have a two data set files `data1` and `data2` each containing 5000 points having 3 columns representing `x,y(coordinate (centroid)),angular movement(theta)` resepectively for two robot movements obtained by numerical programming and solution of a circuit representing robot equations.I need to simulate a graph for coverage with obstacle and without obstacle in a grid like fashion and then calculate the percentage of coverage where A is the coverage for each cell, `A(i)=1` if cell i is covered otherwise 0. I went through this link [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125284/how-to-generate-graph-for-rate-of-traversal) but the answer is too obscure and I cannot follow. Can somebody please tell me how to generate these two graphs?Thank you

Comment: Wut?  Can you please try to reword the question?

Comment: Reframed the question, please have a look.